# Java TCP Connection

Tags: java

How do I create a TCP socket in Java?

How do I create such a TCP connection that it terminates only when I tell it to otherwise it remains open?

How do I use keepalives to know whether the server or client is still available?

Please Help!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> How do I create a TCP socket in Java?

```
Socket socket = new Socket(hostname, port);
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/index.html

> How do I create such a TCP connection that it terminates only when I tell it to otherwise it remains open?

They will remain open until either you or the other end closes it.

> How do I use keepalives to know whether the server or client is still available?

That is up to you.  You can send different messages, one of which is a heartbeat which tells the other end you are alive.

A common thing to do if you are sending binary messages is to send the length as an unsigned short or int value.  I use a message of "length" 0 as a heartbeat.

Comment: Your message of length zero would never get sent unless it has some application protocol around it. I assume that's what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

The class [java.net.Socket](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html) is what you are searching for.